# Relative path in resources folder for README.md file

Tags: java, spring-boot, resources, markdown, relative-path

I am trying to add some images on `README.file` in my Spring Boot app as shown below:

```
### Diagram

<img src="D:\my-project\src\main\resources\images\entity-diagram.png" width="600"/>
```

However, I need to set this path as relative. But I could not set by directly referring resources folder in a smart way something e.g.:

```
<img src="~\images\entity-diagram.png" width="1000"/>
```

So, how can I give reference to the resources folder smartly?

Answer (score 1):

if README.md is parallel to pom.xml (AKA "basedir"):

```html
<img src="./src/main/resources/images/entity-diagram.png" width="600"/>
```

Comment: I did not define basedir on pom.xml. So, I want to follow the most proper way. Normally `<img src="src/main/resources/images/entity-diagram.png" width="600"/>` is working, but not sure if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: There is elegance in a working solution.